# Как обратиться к объекту в его методе?

Tags: c++

**figures.h**

```
class Figure{
protected:int color; 
public:
    Figure(int color) :
      color(color) 
      {}
      virtual double place() const = 0;
      virtual double perimetr() const = 0;
      virtual void output() const = 0;
      virtual bool intersectTo(const Figure &x) = 0; 
      struct Point{
          int x;
          int y;
          Point(int x, int y):
          x(x), y(y) 
          {}
      };

};

    class Circle: public Figure{
        Point center;
        int rad; 
    public:
        Circle(Point center, int rad, int color);
        virtual double place() const;
        virtual double perimetr() const;
        virtual void output() const;
        virtual bool intersectTo(const Figure &x);
    };
```

**figures.cpp**

```
bool Circle::intersectTo(const Figure &x) {

        if (typeid(x) == typeid(Circle)){

            return intersection(?, x);
            }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
    Figure *t = new Triangle(Figure::Point(rand()%100,rand()%100),Figure::Point(rand()%100,rand()%100),Figure::Point(rand()%100,rand()%100),rand()%100);
    Figure *c = new Circle(Figure::Point(100,100),50,1);    
    if(t->intersectTo(*c)){
        std::cout<<"intersect" << std::endl;
        }else {
            std::cout<<"not intersect" << std::endl;
        }
}
```

**Как обратиться к** t в его методе t->intersectTo(*c) что бы проверить на пересечение?**

Comment: @arukasa: `this`?

Comment: @VladD: да я и писал this, но как тогда можно достучаться до полей с координатами, добавлять методы?

intersetction функция принимающая две фигуры и проверяющая их на пересечение, тут она не описана просто.

потому что знаю только typeid =)

Comment: @arukasa: добавлять методы? вы с javascript'ом не путаете?

Comment: @VladD: да вроде не путаю. Как мне в данном случаи лучше достучаться до координат фигуры?

Comment: @arikasa: Не дело внешнего по отношению к классу метода знать внутреннюю кухню фигуры, центр, радиус или что там ещё надо. Пусть лучше `intersectTo` этим занимается, ей и координаты доступны. (Только к указателю на other надо будет применить dynamic_cast.)

Comment: @VladD: Если не сложно, можно последнюю строчку в коде? Я про dynamic_cast

Comment: @arukasa: ну например [так](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

    bool Circle::intersectTo(const Figure& f)
    {
        const Circle* other = dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&f);
        if (other == nullptr)
            throw some_appropriate_exception();

        double dx = other->x - x, dy = other->y - y;
        double centerDistance2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        double radiusSum = other->radius + radius;
        double radiusSum2 = radiusSum * radiusSum;

        return centerDistance2 < radiusSum2;
    }

Comment: Хотя если нужен cast и тем более typeid, похоже, что вы что-то делаете не так. Подумайте, стоит ли объявлять `intersectTo` виртуальной функцией в `Figure`?

Comment: Позвольте с пятью копейками. В Вашем базовом полиморфном классе я не обнаружил деструктора. В соответствии с Мейерсом, если класс имеет виртуальную функцию, он должен иметь ВИРТУАЛЬНЫЙ деструктор.

Comment: @VladD: А что делать если не объявлять её виртуальной функцией? 
C++ занимаюсь только неделю и очень многого не знаю и буду рад советам и если объясните ситуацию или скажите где именно об этом можно почитать.

Почему cast не работает так же с треугольником?
http://ideone.com/x4anjO - 24 строчка не может обратиться, хотя с кругом все нормально работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня закончились комментарии, пишу здесь.

1. А почему не объявлять виртуальной функцией? Что в этом плохого?
2. 24-ая строчка не работает потому, что вы пытаетесь получить доступ к private-полю из кода, не принадлежащего `Triangle`. Только `Triangle` знает подробности своего положения.

Если вы хотите уметь найти пересечение *каждой* фигуры с *любой* другой, да, ваша задача не такая уж и простая. Вам придётся в любом случае выяснять конкретный тип аргументов, виртуальные функции тут вам слабый помощник. Вы можете, например, убрать вообще функцию `intersectTo` из всех классов, кроме `Figure`, вызвать там внешнюю функцию, которой передадите обе сравниваемых фигуры, а эта функция уж пусть делит работу на случаи: выясняет, какие реальные типы аргументов, и вызывает соответствующую подфункцию (это называется диспетчеризацией).

Таким образом вы хоть разгрузите класс `Figure` и его подклассы от не принадлежащей им функциональности.

Answer (score 4):

указатель на обьект внутри его метода this